# How to handle sign in with e-mail after Facebook sign up

Tags: signup-signon, facebook, accounts

My website has 2 different types of sign up/ sign in for user accounts: Facebook and e-mail.

If an user has an e-mail account, he provides us with his e-mail and creates a password, while Facebook only authenticates the user and provides us with basic info (e-mail, name, photo), but no password is required.

Currently, we treat users who have e-mail accounts but **later** sign in with facebook by checking if those e-mails provided match. If so, we ID them as the same user.

But...what about the other way around? If an user has **first** signed up with facebook, we lock that e-mail provided with that user's ID. So if he later tries to sign in with that same e-mail used for facebook, he won't be able to, as he never created a password.

How can I handle that situation? Force a Facebook sign up? E-mail authentication for the password? I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Treat a transition from federated login to mail and password the way you would treat a self-service password reset. Send a message to the address with a one-time link to create a password. Then when the user follows the link, invalidate it and open the change password form.

Comment: Very well. I'm testing that right now. The challenge now is communicating that so light users understand what's going on. Thank you.